# lightning:recordForm fields structure not working in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have what at first seems to be a simple question, but I can't seem to pin it down.  I'm working with the lightning:recordForm, and I'm sending the fields dynamically based off a callout where I'm populating the {!v.fields}.  I have tried multiple ways to structure the variable so that it will render the correct fields, but the best I seem to get is it will render the first field in the list.  Documentation says the structure should be String[] and be in the form of "['Item1', 'Item2']".  Maybe its my own shortcomings on the intricacies of JavaScript types, but I can't get it to work.  Note that one sticking point that may be part of the issue is that my callout returns an object with a string of fields and those need to be split and stored in the list.  Here are the relevant snippets of my code:

```
 <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]"/>
 ...
 <lightning:recordForm objectApiName="{!v.thisObject}"
                                                      fields="{!v.fields}"
                                                      recordTypeId="{!v.selectedRecordType}"
                                                      columns="2"
                                                      oncancel="{!c.handleCancel}"
                                                      onSubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                                                      onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"/>
```

Controller:

```
    var fieldsList = custRecCreateList[i].Fields__c.split(",");      
    for(var j=0; j<fieldsList.length; j++){
                fields[j] = fieldsList[j]; //I've also tried fields.push(fieldsList[j]) here
            }
    ....
    component.set("v.fields", fieldsList);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the complicated dance you're trying to go through:

```
component.set("v.fields",
  custRecCreateList[i].Fields__c.split(",")
);
```

However, one caveat here: if you have extra spaces in the list, that'll screw things up. You might want to go with:

```
component.set("v.fields",
  custRecCreateList[i].Fields__c.split(/,\s*/)
);
```

This trims any extra spaces after the comma.

Comment: You were spot on with the whitespace comment.  That was exactly my problem.  Thanks so much for your help!